# PHP: How to parse a JSON string and get the variables?

Tags: php, json, parsing, parameters

I think I have missed the obvious somewhere, what is the best way to parse parameters which are in the format...

```
'{"phonenumber":"123456", "mobile":"589521215", "website":"www.xfty.co.uk" }'
```

so that I have the individual variables?

Comment: take a look at [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a string with JSON content:

```
$string = '{"phonenumber":"123456","mobile":"589521215","website":"www.xfty.co.uk"}';
```

You can parse it and get an associative array with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$array = json_decode( $string, true );
```

And access the array with:

```
$array["phonenumber"] //will give back '123456'
```

Or, if you prefer to get an `stdClass` object, just use:

```
$object = json_decode( $string );
```

And get it with:

```
$object->phonenumber; //will give back '123456'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input looks like json format. You should use json_decode() to access it's values:

```
<?php
$values = json_decode('{"phonenumber":"123456","mobile":"589521215","website":"www.xfty.co.uk"}');

echo "Phonenumber:" . $values->phonenumber . "<br/>";
echo "Mobile:" . $values->mobile . "<br/>";
echo "Website:" . $values->website . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I had not worked out what the format was called and therefore wasn't able to search for info. I'm sure I can move forward from here - Thanks again.